# GDB: What instruction called frame?

Tags: assembly, gdb, callstack

I'm a bit new to GDB and assembly. I'm trying to reverse engineer a single player game I'm playing in an attempt to make a trainer purely for the learning experience. I first used scanmem in Linux, but the value is never in the same place in memory, so I have to find it every time I play which is time consuming to say the least (especially when I'm trying to track many variables).

So, I'm currently in the process of trying to figure out how I can accurately determine the location of a specific variable at runtime (I tried disabling ASLR to no avail). This led me to GDB. I found the variable I'm concerned with at the moment using memscan and set a watchpoint in GDB successfully. Now, then the value changes the program halts and I can play around with it in GDB. Since this isn't an open source program, I stuck with analyzing the assembly instructions rather than source files.

I've checked out the frame stack at this point and I see that frame 0x000000000050d338 called frame 0x000000000050d0fc. However, how do I know which exact instruction in the calling frame trigged the called to the new frame? I'm attempting to work backwards so that I can hopefully trace the origin of my variable at 0x1a76f5e8 (or some pointer reference to it) to some static place in memory by analyzing function parameters. I also tried using memscan to simply locate the address written to memory -- which would be a pointer to that variable/object to no avail (more than likely it's a member of a class and is in the middle of a memory structure I would imagine).

How can I determine where in the calling frame the call to the current frame was made?

Comment: The return address on the stack should point just past the `CALL` instruction that got you there. If you have standard stack frames, `gdb` will even show you if you use the backtrace command.

Comment: Since this program doesn't have debugging symbols, the backtrace command shows me very limited information: only the frame addresses with no arguments (possibly because they're passed via registers on my x86_64 system? at this point in the program, %rsp points to 0x7fffffffaae4. The contents of 0x7fffffffaae4+4 is 0x00 0x00. Isn't that supposed to be the return address?

Comment: At function entry the return address is at `%rsp`, you can print it using `x/a $rsp`. Also note that in 64 bit mode pointers are obviously 64 bit.

Comment: Hm, from what I read it was at $rsp+4 at function entry. Since I'm stopped in the middle of a function, I don't know if %rsp is going to help me since by this point stuff will have been added to the stack most likely. I think I found the answer by using %rbp+8 instead (as stated [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/)), now I just have to figure out to view that code since I can't scroll up in assembly view for some reason. I can only scroll down.

Comment: If you have a legacy stack frame set up (which is not mandatory) then yes, you can use `rbp+8`. `rsp+4` is nonsense, no matter where you have read it.

Comment: I may have been confusing 32-bit and 64-bit sources most likely. +4 would be a 32-bit address and is nonsense, you're right.

Comment: So, in this situation without debugging info compiled, there is no easier way to get this information with GDB than manually look at the memory using `info reg rbp` and then `x/8h (address from first command)+8`?

Comment: You can do it in a single command: `x/a $rbp+8`

Comment: If you're still interested in reverse engineering, check out this book. It's a great reference: http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0764574817.html